# Looping <tr> is not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, twig

I'm generating `<tr>` and `<td>` tags by using a loop. I want to repeat the `<tr>` elements, but `div.border_box_main_01` is repeating instead.

What am I doing wrong?

```php
{% if  data.about.data.pricing is defined and  data.about.data.pricing is not null %}         

  <div class="border_box_main_01" >

    {% set curr= '' %}
    {% set curr =data.currency %}
    {% set comments_flag=0 %}
    {% set reminder_flag=0 %}
    {% set see_more= data.result|length %}

    {% for key,value in data.result %}

      {# set comments=value.metadata.comment #}
      {% set metadata= value.metadata|length %}                    
      {% set comments= value.metadata[0].comment|length %}
      {% set comments_flag = comments_flag + value.metadata|length%}

      {% if comments_flag > 7 and reminder_flag==0 and key!=1 %}
        {% set reminder_flag=1 %}
        {% set comments_flag=0 %}
        {% set comments_flag = comments_flag + value.metadata|length %}
      {% endif %}

      <div class="datagrid23 {% if key > 1%}fee_hide{%endif%}" {% if key > 1%}style="display:none;"{%endif%}>
        <table class="table">

          {% if reminder_flag ==1 %}
          {% endif %}

          {% if reminder_flag ==1 %}

            <tr>
              <td>{{ value.type }}</td>

              {% set metadatas= value.metadata %}
              {% for key,value in metadatas %}

                <td>{{ curr}}{{ value.amount }}</td></tr>

              {% endfor %}

        </table>
      </div>
```

The output should be as follows:

```
 <div class="border_box_main_01">
   <h1>Fees</h1>
   <hr class="counter_countdown">
   <div class="datagrid23">
     <table class="table">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>Busines Ticket</td>
           <td>Rs 500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>General Public Ticket</td>
           <td>Rs 500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>General Public Tickets Adult</td>
           <td>Rs 50</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Generally tables are made with **two** loops: an internal one for the columns and an external one for the rows. Your code is pretty hard to be read, but I see a single `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the for tag up before you write the  tag so that it is written on each iteraton:

```
   {% if  data.about.data.pricing is defined and  data.about.data.pricing is not null %}
    <div class="border_box_main_01" >
            {% set curr= '' %}
            {% set curr =data.currency %}
            {% set comments_flag=0 %}
            {% set reminder_flag=0 %}
            {% set see_more= data.result|length %}
            {% for key,value in data.result %}

            {# set comments=value.metadata.comment #}
            {% set metadata= value.metadata|length %}

            {% set comments= value.metadata[0].comment|length %}
            {% set comments_flag = comments_flag + value.metadata|length%}
            {% if comments_flag > 7 and reminder_flag==0 and key!=1 %}
            {% set reminder_flag=1 %}
            {% set comments_flag=0 %}
            {% set comments_flag = comments_flag + value.metadata|length %}
            {% endif %}

   <div class="datagrid23 {% if key > 1%}fee_hide{%endif%}" {% if key > 1%}style="display:none;"{%endif%}>
        <table class="table">
            {% if reminder_flag ==1 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if reminder_flag ==1 %}

            {% for key,value in metadatas %}
            <tr>


            <td>{{ value.type }}</td>

            {% set metadatas= value.metadata %}
            <td>{{ curr}}{{ value.amount }}</td></tr>
          {% endfor %}

        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your for loop.
Instead, try something like this:

```
 <div class="datagrid23 {% if key > 1 %}fee_hide{% endif %}" {% if key > 1 %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ value.type }}</td>
            </tr>
                {% set metadatas = value.metadata %}

                {% for key,value in metadatas %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{ curr }}{{ value.amount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: It should be something like this. Try using proper alignment for readability. http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/27/  Also note that {% if %} shouldn't be closed with endif before the else statement